# Configure Jenkins to run MSBuild on Linux Platform

Tags: .net, linux, jenkins, msbuild, centos

Is there a way to configure jenkins to be able to run msbuild on linux platform. I do see msbuild plugin but its configuration under "Global Tool Configuration"is mostly related to windows. Also without the plugin if i try to simply use simple shell script to download whatever it needs to be able to run msbuild or the equivalent on linux host, what would that be. We use centos linux distro and tried all ways to download the dot-net core

sudo rpm -Uvh https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/packages-microsoft-prod.rpm

sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-2.2

Also tried :-

https://medium.com/@hudsonmendes/build-net-4-5-on-linux-in-5-minutes-and-see-what-it-is-like-848ea45fc667

But that also never works. I know we can use windows slave or any machine to achieve this. But all i'm looking for is if there is any way out of the box to be able to build a dot net project on any linux platform (in our case centos) using msbuild or its equivalent for linux.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0):

Actually some .net binaries can be used on Linux: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial (select your distro in the left). Then you can execute your build through a bash.

Comment: i have already tried that and couldn't achieve any success. Now i am trying official dotnet docker image that supports both windows and linux and the latest image i used is microsoft/dotnet and using that tried to build the sln file as "dotnet ****.sln ***arguments***" The build works but then it gives errors like The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.104/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.